# no wired or wireless networking on new install

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, acer

This is a new install of Ubuntu.  I ran 12.04 from a usb drive for a day or so, and had no issues outside of some latency that is more due to the lack of RAM on my aspire one D255e than to OS. I had wireless running with no issue, and wired tested as working also.

I ran the installer and removed Windows .  Now the wireless network is detected but ethernet is not, and neither gets a connection. I disabled proprietary drivers and rebooted, re-enabled the driver, and still neither.

I know nothing of Ubuntu yet! What can I do?

Comment: I have a Acer Aspire One and had this happen with the wireless.
It was caused by the wireless switch I click the switch to enable wireless then rebooted and it worked and to do it like 3 times cause the switch was stupid.

Comment: Please edit your question with following o/p. Open a `terminal` and run `lspci`. You told you have disabled something. can you clarify a bit what you did

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try.

1. Ensure your interface is enabled in the bios.
2. ensure hardware switches are on

Issue the below command to find your hardware.

```
lspci
```

To obtain less results you can also try

```
lspci |grep Ethernet
```

Execute jockey to see if there are any additional drivers you need to install

```
jockey-gtk
```

From this information you can search the various forums for your Ethernet chipset to  find installation procedures.

For your wireless issue the command to see if hardware or software is bocking your driver from working.

```
rfkill list
```

Comment: Is the issue with ethernet or wireless?

Answer (score 0):

Weirdest thing happened. Had to replace the screen. Before going through any of the steps listed, replaced and booted to test that screen is working, log in and wireless auto connected. Cannot say what caused or resolved the issue. Thanks for all your help.